# Export of a custom table style in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010, table-styles

How to export a custom table style in MS Excel 2007/2010?

I know how to export a custom chart, but I can't see how to export a custom table style.

Answer (score 6):

Or you can copy a sheet from a workbook with the custom table style to the target workbook. You can delete the copied sheet afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to create the table style and save it as an `excel template` and use that template whenever you need the style. There is no way to add a table style to `styles`